# Entities Have Visible Text When On Ground (Minecraft 1.9)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have looked around google and have not found an answer to this question, mostly because I do not know what to search or what to call my "problem." I am making an adventure map and I am very advanced with command blocks. I have an item spawning that will

1. Never despawn, and
2. Never be picked up.

The item is  a bow. What I want to do is have the entity display the text "Bow" when the player looks near the entity (like a name tag does!) . I know this is possible, but I haven't figured out how to do it yet. Here is my current command:

```
/summon Item ~ ~2 ~ {Item:{id:minecraft:bow,Count:1},Age:-32768,PickupDelay:32767}
```

If there is already a question answering this, my sincere apologies, I have not found one.

Comment: Upvote for `I am very advanced with command blocks`

Comment: :) @RudolfL.Jelínek

Answer (score 3):

Using the CustomName tag this can be achieved.

```
/summon Item ~ ~2 ~ {Item:{id:minecraft:bow,Count:1},CustomName:"Bow",CustomNameVisible:1,Age:-32768,PickupDelay:32767}
```

This is very simple, only thing is the text is there permanently, not only when you look at it.

Comment: If you set "CustomNameVisible to 0, you should only be able to see it when looking directly at the item"